# Hdmi and Laptop

Tags: sound, suspend, hdmi

i have following question about HDMI : Is there a way to configure the HDMI port , that it doesnt switch off , when I close the laptop lid or the screen goes sleep and locked ?
Background is I want to listen to music over my laptop connected to the TV or sound system but I have to remove all the sleep functions from the laptop. Then when the laptop screen goes off after the adjusted 10min also the music or movie stops. 
thank you in advance for your ideas and help

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the power option to do 'nothing' when the lid is closed. There is no way for your machine to be asleep but still transmit things through HDMI.

Comment: Thanks you nmonti that would help for the lid closing , but what is for the monitor option * blank screen* and the lock function ?